# WittyPi board keep turning off Raspberry

Tags: gpio

I have a Raspberry connected with the WittyPi board.
Been strugling to get it running without it dead locking. 
I have followed the steps in Witty Pi's manual
http://www.uugear.com/doc/WittyPi_UserManual.pdf
and from this guide for the green jumper.
http://www.uugear.com/portfolio/change-the-pin-that-used-by-witty-pi/
I got the Raspberry running, changed the daemon.sh so instead of GPIO4 pin 7, I changed it to the GPIO8 pin 24.
I made a shutdown, so that i could move the jumper, connect the jumper pin to Pin24 (GPIO8) and my DS18B20 temperature sensor to GPIO4.
When I try to start up the Raspberry, it runs some of the startup script, but at some point, it starts to stop all the scripts, and then shuts down.

I have tryed to reinstall jessie and start up from scrath with no code installed.

Anyone got experience with the Witty Pi? Who have had the same kind of problem?

**EDIT**
It get to the login in terminal, few seconds later it starts to shut down.

Comment: what kind of power supply is your pi using?

Answer (score 0):

Pin 24 is not GPIO 24.

```
GPIO       pin  pin    GPIO
3V3         1    2      5V
0/2 (SDA)   3    4      5V
1/3 (SCL)   5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
21/27      13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

If the GPIO column has a V it indicates the pin is connected to the power rail and not a GPIO.

Where 2 figures are shown separated by a / the first figure is the GPIO number used on the first revision Pi B boards.

Comment: My bad, GPIO 24 was an type error i meant GPIO8 pin 24.

Comment: GPIO8 will be driven high if you use SPI.  Which GPIO are you using to power-down the Pi?

Comment: Default it uses GPIO4(pin7) for halt. I have changed it to GPIO8(pin24).

Comment: Try GPIO 22/23/24.

Comment: If you want to use a different pin for this purpose, you need to choose a pin that:
 •gets initiated as input pin
 •has default HIGH state
Taken from WittyPi's guide I linked to.

Comment: "gpio readall" says they are not high state.

Comment: GPIO 0-8 are the only ones which default high at boot.  I2C potentially uses 0-3.  SPI potentially uses 7-8.  That leaves 4, 5, and 6 as possibilities.